# Laravel couldn't submit forms due to cache

Tags: php, laravel-5

My Laravel forms won't submit without clearing the cache. I've cleared my cache `CTRL + F5` (clear cache) and form submission worked.Or else When I click submit for 3 or 4 times the page gets refreshed not submitted. How I do I solve this issue?

Here is my updated code:

```
     {!! Form::open(array('route' =>   
                'category.store','method'=>'POST','files'=>true)) !!}
            {!! csrf_field() !!}

        @if(count($errors))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.
            <br/>
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
      @endif

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">     
    {{ Form::label('Car Type', 'Car Type') }}
    {{ Form::text('cartype', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('cartype') }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   {{ Form::close() }}
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'cartype' => 'required|unique:car_category',

    ],
    [
    'image' => 'Please choose an image having extension jpg,png or jpeg.',
        'mimes' => 'Please choose an image having extension jpg,png or jpeg.',
        'integer' => 'Please enter valid value.',
        'between:1,12' => ' The Available seats must between 1 to 12.',
        'cartype.required' => ' The Car Type field is required.',

        ])->validate();


    $picture = new Car;

    $picture->cartype = Input::get('cartype');

    $picture->save();

}
```

Comment: generate a random variable in your controller and pass it as GET variable to your form action link

Comment: Did you included csrf_field() in your form?

Comment: Create csrf_filed() in this form or you should be excluded from CSRF verification

Comment: Show some of your code, how you implement the form and how you handle it.

Comment: Thanks  all for your reply.I'll try it

Comment: Included csrf_field but it not works

Comment: code  updated....

Comment: When you say it doesnt get submitted, what do you mean? Does the page not refresh? Or is the controller not executed? Can you show the code for the controller for the route `category.store`?

Comment: When submit the form It 'ld call the controller function store ,but the form simply gets refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove `{!! csrf_field() !!}` from your form.
your form should be like.

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' =>   
            'category.store','method'=>'POST','files'=>true)) !!}

    @if(count($errors))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.
        <br/>
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
  @endif

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">     
{{ Form::label('Car Type', 'Car Type') }}
{{ Form::text('cartype', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
<span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('cartype') }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

{{ Form::close() }}